# После перевода с sqlite на MySQL не получается загрузить дамп базы данных, если я правильно понял ошибку. Как это исправить?

Tags: mysql, django

Мои действия по порядку:

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE DATABASE 'someapp' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE USER 'django'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'someapp'.* TO 'django'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 --exclude=contenttypes > datadump.json

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'database': 'grizzly',
            'user': 'user',
            'password': 'password',
        }
    }
}

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

Все было хорошо, но вот когда я запускаю последнюю команду я получаю ошибку:
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 727: invalid continuation byte**

```
$ python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\Desktop\hotelOrder\grizzly\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\Desktop\hotelOrder\grizzly\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "C:\Users\Vladik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 67, in Deserializer
    stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 727: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что данные дампятся в UTF8?

Comment: а как это проверить ?

Comment: делал все по гайду https://tproger.ru/articles/django-sqlite-to-mysql/